# TypeORM connection not found on test

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm studying clean architecture with TDD by creating a simple application, and I'm trying to implement the UserRepository on my infrastructure layer, but I'm getting this error `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.` even after I've established a connection before running the test itself.

[image: Jest Error]

This is my UserEntity class.

```js
import { PrimaryColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, Entity } from 'typeorm'

@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @Column()
  name: string

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string

  @Column()
  password: string

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date
}
```

In this UserRepository, I'm implementing a `CreateUserRepository` that has the `create` methods below. To read the TypeORM repository I'm using the `getRepository` method from TypeORM

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm'

import { CreateUserRepositoryDTO, CreateUserRepository } from '../../../../data/protocols/db/user/CreateUserRepository'
import { UserModel } from '../../../../domain/models/UserModel'
import { UserEntity } from '../entities/UserEntity'

export class UserRepository implements CreateUserRepository {
  private ormRepository: Repository<UserEntity>

  constructor () {
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(UserEntity)
  }

  async create (userData: CreateUserRepositoryDTO): Promise<UserModel> {
    const user = await this.ormRepository.create(userData)
    const result = await this.ormRepository.save(user)
    return result
  }
}
```

```js
import { mockCreateUserRepositoryDTO } from '../../test/mockCreateUserRepositoryDTO'
import { createTestConnection } from '../helpers/TypeORMHelper'
import { UserRepository } from './UserRepository'

describe('UserRepository', () => {
  it('Should return User on create Success', async () => {
    await createTestConnection()
    const userData = mockCreateUserRepositoryDTO()
    const sut = new UserRepository()
    const user = await sut.create(userData)
    console.log(user)
  })
})
```

```js
import { createConnection, Connection, ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm'

import { postgresCreds, schemaConfig } from '../../../../../ormconfig'

async function createDbConnection (options: ConnectionOptions): Promise<Connection> {
  try {
    const connection: Connection = await createConnection(options)
    console.log(`TypeORM Connected to ${options.database}`)
    return connection
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Problem with TypeORM connection')
    throw err.message
  }
}

export async function createTestConnection () {
  return createDbConnection({
    name: 'testConnection',
    type: 'postgres',
    database: 'market-list-test',
    synchronize: false,
    ...postgresCreds,
    ...schemaConfig,
    logging: ['error']
  })
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to your specific issue but your repository has serious testability issues. `UserRepository` wraps and orm Repository but that repository needs to be provided externally. Other words, its constructor should take either a repository or repository factory (i.e. TypeORM'S `getRepository` as a parameter. In a testable system, dependency creation should not take place inside dependents. This is a Bedrock of TDD in practice, and it also just makes your code better

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've thought about passing the connection or the `getRepository` in the constructor and that probably is the best practice and I'll do a refactor using that. What I've done to fix that issue temporarily, probably not the best solution, I've created a 'Singleton' to manage that connection. https://gist.github.com/bmviniciuss/f74ee849f5f2aa3bcbe6b9530878feda and in the constructor I call this Singleton `getRepository`, but again probably not the best fix.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with having utility for assisting with connections but I think it doesn't make sense to create a class like that. Just export some constants and functions. The singleton pattern isn't really something you apply in JavaScript because objects exist independently of classes and you can export variables and functions. In other words, every top-level declaration is a singleton. Note that TypeORM'S `getRepository` is an example.